# Videos from Youtube with the same volume

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I embed videos from Youtube to my website. Various videos have different volume. I need to set these videos to the same volume level. It is possible get this using Javascript? I can not normalize these videos and reupload.

Comment: The only reference I've been able to find is http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/how-to-removedecrease-sound-volume-on-embedded-youtube-video-html5-player/71264, but a recent comment implies that this may no longer work.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is not a solution for me :(. This sets the volume to all videos, including those that would need to set the volume differently.

Comment: I suspect it's not possible then, unfortunately.